# can `public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0` be written as `public(get) private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0`?

Tags: swift, get, set, getter, access-control

I'm new to Swift and its trying to learn the concept of access control. I saw this code in "the swift programming language 2.1". I understand the code `"public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0"` means that for the variable numberOfEdits, it has a public getter and a private setter.

My question is, can `public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0` be written as `public(get) private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0` to clearly indicate that numberOfEdits has a public getter?

```
public struct TrackedString {
    public private(set) var numberOfEdits = 0
    public var value: String = "" {
        didSet {
            numberOfEdits++
        }
    }
    public init() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the getter always has the access level of the unqualified access control label. You can override the setter's level to be *lower than* the getter's level with either `private(set)` or `internal(set)`.

Comment: “Each access-level modifier above optionally accepts a single argument, which consists of the 'set' keyword enclosed in parentheses (for instance, private(set)).”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Comment: Section: Language Reference, Subsection: Access Control Levels